# Show hidden icons in icon tray through group policy

Tags: group-policy, undo, system-sounds

Had previously hidden the icon tray through group policy and would now like to add the volume control/sound icon back to the tray. I have disabled the "hide the notification area" and forced the gpupdate. I may be missing something, but only the start button, task bar, and clock appears.

Comment: Which version of windows?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 for Group Policy; Windows 7 on the machines itself

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the fact that when you set a group policy to "Not Configured" you are setting the *policy* to Not Configured.  Which means you are not enforcing the policy, which means the client will use whatever it's (currently) set to.

If you want to 'revert' settings previously enforced by a policy you have to leave it Enabled but configure it the way you want it (ie: configure the policy to show the icon); So if you want it to go back to the default settings on the client, then you have to determine what those default settings were, and enforce them via policy.